# he and his wife OR him and his wife?

Tags: difference, pronouns

I'm asking my readers to read a blog of my friend Kevin and his wife's celebration of their daughter's life.

Should I say:

> I've met Kevin awhile back. Read about **he and his wife's** amazing story.

or

> I've met Kevin awhile back. Read about **him and his wife's** amazing story.

Which one is correct?

Comment: The first sentence isn't correct. _**I'd** met Kevin **a while** back._

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways you could word this. As for which option to choose, try omitting *"and his wife's"* and see what happens:

> Read about he amazing story.
>
> Read about him amazing story.

Clearly, both of those are wrong, and they can't be fixed by adding "and his wife's".

So, first let's fix the short version somehow. These are all viable candidates:

> Read about him and his amazing story.
> Read his amazing story.
> Read this amazing story about him.

Now, let's put his wife back into the narrative:

> Read about him, his wife and their amazing story.
> Read his and his wife's amazing story.
> Read this amazing story about him and his wife.

Of those last three, the middle one sounds a little off to me. I'd choose one of the others on this list, or reword it in some other way.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

*I've met Kevin awhile back. Read about his and his wife's amazing story.* if you are talking about Kevin and his wife's story (both of their stories)

*I've met Kevin awhile back. Read about him and his wife's amazing story.* if you are trying to imply that it is only the wife's story.

It is definitely not the 1st answer.